# How to make video with moving text and objects?

Tags: video, youtube, animation

I want to make a video with moving text and objects like in the youtube video link below.

What options/tools should I explore? Only think i can think of is making animations in Powerpoint, recording the full screen as video and then later adding audio/music to it.

Any better options?

*newbie alert* - I am a coder, so not very good with making videos - but willing to learn/explore all options.